# Can anybody share android app code for magento REST api

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I wanted sample android application which uses magento RESTful services ..so that i can browse all the products , catalog , customers , checkout and etc.

Comment: check this http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html

Comment: Madam I have done that..But now i am looking for sample android application code .which request atleast localhost for the list of products through Android Mobile

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this github https://github.com/sudhirbelagali/SnowDogSoapAndroid ,

which uses SOAP webservice calls , and let me know if anything you want

Comment: can you explain when token entry is created in authorized oauth tokens grid.

Comment: I have php code , Let me know if you need